# RegisterExpandoAttribute - Throwing Error

Tags: asp.net, custom-attributes, clientscriptmanager

Recently, I discovered that using: someControl.Attributes.Add("customAttr", "customVal") is not compatible with all web browsers. The recommended registration for custom attributes is:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(someControl.ClientID, "customAttr", "customVal")
```

Okay, here's the problem.  I am using a ListView to generate a custom control. In certain scenarios, the ListView must be refreshed/recreated.  When this happens, and a ListView item attempts the register (in this case, re-register) the expando attribute, the page throws the following error:

An entry with the same key already exists.

Obviously RegisterExpandoAttribute() does not behave like the Page.Cache object where if a key already exists, the current value is overwritten.  I can easily hack my way past this problem but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution to this. For example, there is no method like: Page.ClientScript.IsExpandoAttributeRegistered(...)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a custom control, try doing the `RegisterExpandoAttribute` call during the control `PreRender`.  I was having issues with the attribute still being registered if the control had been removed and doing that fixed my issue.  I would imagine that if you're calling `RegisterExpandoAttribute` in the `PreRender` for the control then it shouldn't be called more than once per page load.